# How to change only my user name?

Tags: boot

how do i can change my username Ubuntu?
because i tried one more time to change my own username, so please help me to this question about user change. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Read `man 5 passwd` to see the fields in `/etc/passwd`, and use `sudo vipw --passwd` to edit `/etc/passwd`, OR, read `man chfn` and use `chfn`.

Remember that the changes in `/etc/passwd` only take effect when you go through the login process.

Whenever one makes changes to the authentication mechanism, one should ensure that one is logged in another terminal to avoid locking oneself out of the system through error.